# Jboss OSGI, eclipse gemini blueprint, invalid bundle activator

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to add `eclipse-gemini-blueprint` to `wildfly 7.2` (`ex-jboss`)

I added the following capabilities in `standalone-osgi.xml`:

```
<capability name="personal.org.springframework.aop" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.springframework.asm" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.springframework.beans" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.springframework.context" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.springframework.core" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.springframework.expression" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.com.springsource.aopalliance" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.com.springsource.apachecommons" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.com.springsource.aspectjtools" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.eclipse.gemini-blueprint.core" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.eclipse.gemini-blueprint.extender" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="personal.org.eclipse.gemini-blueprint.io" startlevel="1"/>
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBOSGI011026: Framework Error: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: JBOSGI011254: Cannot start bundle: org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender:2.0.0.M02
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.spi.AbstractBundleAdaptor.start(AbstractBundleAdaptor.java:223) [jbosgi-framework-core-2.1.0.CR12.jar:2.1.0.CR12]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.StartLevelImpl.increaseStartLevel(StartLevelImpl.java:246) [jbosgi-framework-core-2.1.0.CR12.jar:2.1.0.CR12]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.FrameworkActive.createServiceValue(FrameworkActive.java:149) [jbosgi-framework-core-2.1.0.CR12.jar:2.1.0.CR12]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.FrameworkActive.createServiceValue(FrameworkActive.java:105) [jbosgi-framework-core-2.1.0.CR12.jar:2.1.0.CR12]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.spi.AbstractIntegrationService.start(AbstractIntegrationService.java:60) [jbosgi-framework-core-2.1.0.CR12.jar:2.1.0.CR12]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: JBOSGI011253: Invalid bundle activator: org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.boot.ChainActivator
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.spi.AbstractBundleAdaptor.start(AbstractBundleAdaptor.java:209) [jbosgi-framework-core-2.1.0.CR12.jar:2.1.0.CR12]
        ... 9 more
```

Previously I had some missing dependencies in modules and I added them manually...

What can I do to fix this? this error isn't telling me that much...

Comment: I tried to run Gemini Bluprint with latest wildfly (8.0.0.Alpha1) and it worked fine. As per the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.osgi.framework/jbosgi-framework-core/2.1.0.CR12/org/jboss/osgi/framework/spi/AbstractBundleAdaptor.java?av=f#209) it appears that issue is related to classloading, might be multiple OSGi classes getting packaged

Comment: and you are adding the capabilities like I do? or how do you add everything?... also.. please add an answer.. so that I can accept it

Comment: if you just added that jars in that deployment folder it's not working :)  (gemini blueprint is not working.. it's just being ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Adding following dependencies to the standalone-osgi.xml leads to a working Blueprint config with [Wildfly 8.0.0.Alpha1](http://www.wildfly.org/download/)

```xml
<capability name="org.eclipse.gemini:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core:1.0.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.eclipse.gemini:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender:1.0.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.eclipse.gemini:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io:1.0.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.springframework:org.springframework.aop:3.2.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.springframework:org.springframework.beans:3.2.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.springframework:org.springframework.core:3.2.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.springframework:org.springframework.context:3.2.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.springframework:org.springframework.expression:3.2.2.RELEASE" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging:1.1.1" startlevel="1"/>
<capability name="org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:1.0.0" startlevel="1"/>
```

With these capabilities I was able to get a simple Blueprint Hello World bundle work

**Note**: This is the first time I was using the Jboss OSGi so not sure how to customize the embedded Maven artifact resolver. The artifacts used above are not present on Maven central and instead need to be fetched from [Spring Repo](http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external). However as per [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/199029) its not possible to add third party repositories. So I had to pre fetch them in my local repo separately. If there is a better way then let me know